# Django return method parameter

Tags: python, django

I was watching a tutorial on django and the guy added the following line of code, however he didnt exactly explain what it does.

```
return '%s - %s' django
```

the full code line is:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s - %s' % (self.post, self.author)
```

and i do understand it, just not that return part. Anyone mind clearing it out for me.

Comment: You construct a string, and then you return this, this is thus the result of calling the `.__str__()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be found in models sometimes. It helps during debugging - when you print this object, it will call `__str__` and return that instead of some random print message like `Something object at 0xsomeadress`.

Print will call the `__str__` function on an object to retrieve a string representation which it will later on output to stdout.

It is also useful when using the UI that Django generates, as it shows the message that is returned by `__str__`.

Comment: the __str__ method i understand, my question with the { '%s - %s'  } part of the code.

Comment: That's just substitution - each `%s` is substituted by each variable after the `%`, one by one.